# How to stop AsyncFacebookRunner or stop a request in general?

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask, facebook-android-sdk

I have an `AsyncFacebookRunner` that uploads an image to Facebook. I want to create a cancel button that will stop the download.

How can one achieve that?

**EDIT:**

This is how I use it:

```
byte[] data = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putByteArray("picture", data);
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", 
new PhotoUploadListener(dialog), null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always extend the `AsyncFacebookRunner` class and override the `request` method.
Something like this:

```
public class CancelableAsyncFacebookRunner extends AsyncFacebookRunner {
    private Thread requestThread;

    public AsyncFacebookRunner(Facebook fb) {
        super(fb);
    }

    @Override
    public void request(final String graphPath,
            final Bundle parameters,
            final String httpMethod,
            final RequestListener listener,
            final Object state) {

        this.requestThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String resp = fb.request(graphPath, parameters, httpMethod);
                    listener.onComplete(resp, state);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    listener.onFileNotFoundException(e, state);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    listener.onMalformedURLException(e, state);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    listener.onIOException(e, state);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void cancel() {
        this.requestThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

It hasn't been tested, but should give you the general idea.

---

## Edit

Now that I think about it, this makes little sense, since you want to use the `AsyncFacebookRunner` to make multiple requests and the `cancel` will cancel the last request only.

I would suggest returning the thread and then have the ability to interupt it somewhere else, but you can't change the signature of the method like this and creating a new method won't make it possible to use other `request` methods defined in the `AsyncFacebookRunner` class.

Instead you can do something like:

```
public class CancelableAsyncFacebookRunner extends AsyncFacebookRunner {
    private Hashtable<String, Thread> requestThreads;

    public AsyncFacebookRunner(Facebook fb) {
        super(fb);
        this.requestThreads = new Hashtable<String, Thread>();
    }

    @Override
    public void request(final String id, 
            final String graphPath,
            final Bundle parameters,
            final String httpMethod,
            final RequestListener listener,
            final Object state) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String resp = fb.request(graphPath, parameters, httpMethod);
                    requestThreads.remove(id);
                    listener.onComplete(resp, state);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    requestThreads.remove(id);
                    listener.onFileNotFoundException(e, state);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    requestThreads.remove(id);
                    listener.onMalformedURLException(e, state);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    requestThreads.remove(id);
                    listener.onIOException(e, state);
                }
            }
        });

        this.requestThreads.put(id, thread);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void cancel(String id) {
        if (this.requestThreads.containsKey(id) {
            this.requestThreads.get(id).interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to generate an id somehow for the request, can be something simple like:

```
String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: I noticed that I forgot to start the thread, so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
AsyncFacebookRunner fbRunner;

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    fbRunner.cancel(true);
}
```

Calling this will also not invoke onPostExecute(Object) so you need to take note of this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

Comment: AsyncFacebookRunner dosen't have a cancel method.

Comment: Just had a look here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner.java and it seems like it has nothing that you could cancel the request with sorry.

Comment: Ya i saw in the file as well, i was thinking about adding some code to it and bypass it somehow. any idea how to do what?

Comment: Do you actually have the class files or is it like a jar?

Comment: Also what method are you using to upload the picture? Code would help for me to understand how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an elegant solution but you may be able to interrupt the thread the `AsyncFacebookRunner` is using, handle the resulting exception and gracefully cancel the comms.

Alternatively would you consider forking from the repository and adding your own cancel method to the code?

**EDIT**

Look at how `AsyncTask` is implemented in the google source repository. Essentially you need to be able to call a method from any thread that sets a cancelled flag, this would normally be a

```
private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
// volatile ensures you always get up to date value when checking across threads

public void cancel() {
    cancelled = true;
}

public boolean isCancelled() {
    return cancelled;
}
```

As you cancel the task your method would set this to true and you would check it at regular intervals from your `AsyncFacebookRunner` thread.

Comment: If that's the only option then it's ok, but how should i implement such a method?