# Android Facebook SDK cancel a Photo upload request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to create an Android application to Post a Photo with some description to a facebook fan page.
Here is the code I used for posting.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("description ", "Photo description");
params.putParcelable("source", bitmap);

RequestAsyncTask requestAsyncTask = new Request(session, "/page_id/photos", params,
            HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

Here I used **Request** and **RequestAsyncTask** Classes from Facebook SDK.

Upload progress will be shown in notification bar, taping on it will allow users to cancel upload, 
I tried

```
     requestAsyncTask.cancel(true);
```

But it's not working because it allows AsyncTask's **doInBackground()** (photo upload task done inside doInBackground()) to finish execution, so photo will be posted even after cancelling. Is there a way to terminate from **doInBackground()** or any Facebook API methods to cancel a Request?

Comment: You need to implement your own async. Refer this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984531/how-to-stop-asyncfacebookrunner-or-stop-a-request-in-general